# Telerik RadGridView change cell color depending of another cell value using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I'm using `Telerik RadGridView`. I'm trying to change the color of one cell depending on the value of another cell. I'm trying to achieve this using this code:

```
if (e.Column.Name == "colDate" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.CellElement.Value.ToString()))
{
    if (DateTime.Now > DateTime.Parse(e.CellElement.Value.ToString()))
    {
        e.Row.Cells["colColor"].Style.DrawFill = true;
        e.Row.Cells["colColor"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        e.Row.Cells["colColor"].Style.NumberOfColors = 1;
    }
}
```

But for some reason it doesn't change the color. What I noticed is that when i replace

`e.Row.Cells["colColor"].Style`

with

`e.CellElement`

it changes the color. But then it changes the color of the wrong cell (what is totally logical because it's on the current cell). But I don't want to change the current cell.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I asked this question on Telerik forum again and there is the correct answer. Have a [look](http://www.telerik.com/forums/change-telerik-radgridview-cell-color-depending-on-another-cell-value)

Answer (score 0):

You can use rule based formatting objects this is documented in the telerik api docs.

Their code example looks like this

```
ConditionalFormattingObject obj = new ConditionalFormattingObject("MyCondition", ConditionTypes.Greater, "30", "", false);
obj.CellBackColor = Color.SkyBlue;
obj.CellForeColor = Color.Red;
obj.TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
this.radGridView1.Columns["UnitPrice"].ConditionalFormattingObjectList.Add(obj);
```

To explain this creates a rule called `MyCondition` which says if this cell value is greater than 30 then make the background colour of the cell SkyBlue and the Foreground Colour Red. Align the contents of the cell to middle right and bind it to a column called UnitPrice.